# removing bulletpoints on resume

Tags: cv

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}
```

I was able to remove bullet points by adding [] to

```
\item
```

but I can't figure out how to remove bullet points on

```
\resumeitem
```

and

```
\resumesubitem
```

Is there an easy way to remove just the bullet point and keep the heading? If so, please help me out! I am new to latex :(

Comment: Do you want to remove the bullet points for all resumeitems or just some of them?

Comment: I wish I could post what the pdf looks like, but to answer your question, pretty much all of them. resumeitem seems to have the main bullet point, and has sub bullet points, and I just want to get rid of the main one.

Comment: Does `\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{\item[]{\small\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}}` help?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Do I add that line onto the code, or do I edit one of the lines like that?

Comment: Just add `[]` within the definition you already have.

Comment: @TeXnician that's an answer

Comment: @DaiBowen Might be, but is it even clear what the OP wants ("pretty much all of them")?

Comment: @TeXnician "resumeitem seems to have the main bullet point, and has sub bullet points, and I just want to get rid of the main one." seems sufficient, otherwise what do you need the OP to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe in your question you need to add `[]` to `\item` to remove the bullet points. Currently `\resumeitem` is a wrapper around `\item`; hence, you need to change the definition and add your fix.

This removes the bullet points:

```
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{\item[]{\small\textbf{#1}{: #2\vspace{-2pt}}}
```